# translate scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d's binnumber to a x,y bin

Tags: python, scipy, binning

One of scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d's output is `binnumber`, which, according to the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) is "an integer that represents the bin in which this observation falls." However, I have no idea how to use this to get an actual x,y bin.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setup random data
data = np.random.randn(200,3)


#Specify limits of binned data
xmin = -3.; xmax = 3.
ymin = -3.; ymax = 3.

bins, xb, yb, binnum = scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(data[:,0],
                            data[:,1],
                            data[:,2],
                            statistic = np.std,
                            bins=10,range=[[xmin,xmax],[ymin,ymax]])
```

So, because I'm asking it to bin 10x10, I have 100 bins.  This is reflected when checking `bins`, as it has 10 rows of 10 elements each.  However, I have no idea what binnumber is referring to, because when I check `binnum`, I get an array with integers going up to like 120 or 130.  So what bins could these numbers possibly be referring to?  I'd like to be able to take an element of binnumber and get the value of that bin in `bins`, but I can't figure out how to make sense of scipy's output.

Answer (score 1):

Passing `bins=10` defines 10 bins plus 2 bins at the boundaries of each dimension. One for `x < -3` and another for `x >= 3` in your case.

Thus you effectively get `12x12` bins, with a bin number ranging from `0 to 143`